# How to create VirtualHost in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I had followed many articles to 'How to create VirtualHost in Ubuntu'. This is what have I done

**Installed Apache**

```
sudo apt-get  install lamp-server^ phpmyadmin
```

I created folder called `site1.com` in /var/www/

Then I have created the file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com`

Then added the following code to that `site1.com` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    ServerAdmin mifas@site1.com
    ServerAlias site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com

    # Other directives here
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/site1.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then after that I edit the host file added the following line of code

```
127.0.0.1   site1.com
```

**Edit**
Also I enable the site1.com via `sudo a2ensite site1.com`

Then i restart the apache serivice. (Even i restarted the pc)

When I go to the site1.com, It will say `The connection has timed out` Error Message. But I can browse via `localhost/site1.com`. I have been trying since last two days. No solution. And followed many articles and videos.

Comment: trying changing the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf` and then try.

Comment: or just add the .conf ext to the file name i.e, site1.com.conf